# Group VOIP calling in Android

Tags: android, audio, sip, voip, audio-streaming

What's up guys! Haven't asked a question on SO in a while and I feel a bit out of touch, haha. Anyways, I've recently discovered the wonderful world of voice call over the web using [VOIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_over_IP) and [WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC)

I'm doing some R&D for an idea that I have, and I basically would love the answer to the following questions, by someone who has extensive knowledge in this area and/or has worked on applications that uses this feature over the years. I'll try to keep them simple

1) What are the main differences between VOIP and WebRTC?

2) Which is better suited for a mobile app?

3) Is it possible to achieve a group or "conference" like session where more than 2 people are on an audio call?

4) I've also discovered that Android has built in APIs for [SIP](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html), or [Session Initiation Protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_Initiation_Protocol), but I've read conflicting blogs about their usefulness. Namely there is a lack of support for many modern codecs, etc. I'm not too familiar with this either so any clarification or insight on this would be helpful as well!

5) What are some of the best or most popular libraries for working with this kind of stuff?

Again, completely new to this stuff but find it very exciting. Any help from an experienced person in this area would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. VOIP is sending Voice over Internet Protocols (IP).
   There are different technologies to do that like WebRTC etc.(HTTP is only text based, so for voice and video we have to look for some other real time transfer protocol. right? and other part is you want to connect from Internet to PSTN(Public Switch Telephone Network)).
2. Android has built-in APIs for SIP but that doesn't support for many of codecs. So the solution is use some other third party API in your app i.e. Jain SIP etc. or build your own API.

Here is some doc which describes call flow of from SIP to PSTN.    [ref doc link](https://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/Telecom/SIP_PSTN_Call_Flow.pdf) and you have to be familiar with SIP server i.e. Asterisk etc.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) What are the main differences between VOIP and WebRTC?

WebRTC is a way to route media for VoIP, commonly used in modern browsers but also in apps. Traditionally for VoIP we have used H.323 or SIP as the signaling protocol and RTP for the media. WebRTC doesn't specify the signaling (usually SIP is used in websocket, but you can use also other methods such as HTTP AJAX requests). WebRTC is all about peer to peer media routing. A black box in the browsers providing a simple JavaScript API which can be easily integrated with SIP. I am talking about browsers here because WebRTC was designed primarily for browsers to have a built-in method to make VoIP calls without the need of any plugins such as Java or Flash.
The transport protocol for WebRTC is SRTP in DTLS.

> 2) Which is better suited for a mobile app?

It depends on your goals. If you wish to make regular calls (for example calls to mobile/landline via SIP) then a softphone is much better since it has total control. However if you already have a WebRTC server and most of the calls are peer to peer (user to user within the same server) then WebRTC might be better. In overall, SIP softphones are better quality apps for now and there are a few high quality free softphone apps such as [MizuDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mizuvoip.mizudroid.app) or [CSipSimple](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.csipsimple)

> 3) Is it possible to achieve a group or "conference" like session where more than 2 people are on an audio call?

This is possible with both SIP and WebRTC (if you have a softswitch, then the conference can be handled also on the server side, without any support by the client app)

> 4) I've also discovered that Android has built in APIs for SIP

Forget about it. It is a low quality implementation with many problems and lack of important codec's such as G.729. I would recommend to start with an open source sip stack or get a branded softphone for your needs from a company specialized on this such as the mizutech [customized softhone](https://www.mizu-voip.com/Software/Softphones/CustomizedSoftphone.aspx).

> 5) What are some of the best or most popular libraries for working
>   with this kind of stuff?

If you wish to do it yourself, then I can recommend [CSipSimple](https://github.com/r3gis3r/CSipSimple) and [SIPDroid](https://github.com/i-p-tel/sipdroid)